# How to build and deploy Reactjs to docker

Tags: reactjs, docker, deployment, build, docker-build

I have developed sample application using ReactJS and able to run in localhost.Everything is fine. My doubt is like what is the build steps for deploying in the docker. Could someone help me out with your quick answer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://link.medium.com/fwNBizGhMR

Comment: Please elaborate your question i.e. which kind of web server are you going to use e.g. nginx. And what did you try so far?

Comment: Thanks @SakoBu i will check with this solution

Comment: Thanks@vahdet. Basically i have created the reactjs application. Then for build process we have moved my code to Docker container, and added docker file(at root of application) which contains commands to run application. Basically i just want to host my application to one the ipaddress. Could you please help me out